# Strange(?) behaviour of `summary()` inside a pipe

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse, magrittr

Me and a couple of colleagues are wondering why

```
N <- rnorm(16) %>% matrix(., ncol = 4) %>% `colnames<-`(letters[1:4]) %T>% summary()
```

or

```
N <- rnorm(16) %>% matrix(., ncol = 4) %>% `colnames<-`(letters[1:4]) %T>% summary() %>% `+`(., 0)
```

do not work (summary is not printed), while

```
N <- rnorm(16) %>% matrix(., ncol = 4) %>% `colnames<-`(letters[1:4]) %T>% {print(summary(.))}
```

does?

Answer (score 9):

There's no reason for `summary` to print its output any more than `rnorm` or `matrix` or any of the other functions in the pipeline. Printing is generally suppressed when there is assignment `<-`.

```
N <- rnorm(16) %>% matrix(., ncol = 4) %>% `colnames<-`(letters[1:4]) %T>% summary()
# no printing

N <- 5
# no printing

M <- rnorm(16) %>% matrix(., ncol = 4) %>% `colnames<-`(letters[1:4])
# no printing

M %>% summary
summary(M)
# prints

sM <- M %>% summary
sM <- summary(M)
# no printing
# assignment prevents implicit printing.
```

An explicit `print` call creates a side-effect (printing), which is what you want to happen.

The tee pipe `%T>%` doesn't create any side-effects (like printing), it just returns the LHS so that if you `%T>%` into a function that **does** create side-effects but does not return it's input (like `plot()`), you can get those side effects while still piping the input to another step.

Note that **`print` does return its argument** (invisibly), so you don't actually need the tee pipe `%T>%` with `print`.